# getGroupView expandedlist android getting called multiple times for each tap on group

Tags: android, navbar, expandablelistview

I have 2 groups and their respective items.
When I tap on the first group it expands & then following it I tap on the second group, both shows proper data based on group-position.

But when I closed the first group the data in the second group changed, I mean I am getting wrong group position i.e 0 for the first group.

Also If I directly expand the second group it shows incorrect data due to wrong group-position.

I observed through the log, every time I clicked on any group, the getgroupview method gets called for two times for each group & respectively the child also.

```
public class NavAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private List<String> _listDataHeaderCaption;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public NavAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,List<String> listDataHeaderCaption,HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataHeaderCaption = listDataHeaderCaption;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {


                    Log.d(AppConstants.MyLogs,"0 : "+headerTitle);
                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                    txtListChild.setText(childText);
       }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
   return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {

    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    String headerCaptionTitle = (String) _listDataHeaderCaption.get(groupPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    TextView lblListHeaderCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderCaption);
    lblListHeaderCaption.setText(headerCaptionTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

[CORRECT ORDER WHEN BOTH GROUPS OPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTPli.jpg)
[WRONG - WHEN SECOND GROUP IS OPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh2eQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getChildView` method is wrong... Currently, you are setting the proper text only when the view is null. However, some views are re-used... So, you always have to update the text.

Update it as follows:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    Log.d(AppConstants.MyLogs,"Position: " + position + ": Text: " + childText);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    if(txtListChild != null) {
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `BaseExpandableListAdapter` you have override `hasStableIds()` method which **returns true** instead of **false** as following.

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```